# Display partname in memoir class with babel and French

Tags: memoir, babel, parts, french

I would like to have the `\partname` (Part) display in the table of content.

Example:

**Part II: This is the title of my part 2**

instead of

**"II This is the title of my part 2"**

For now, I use this:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Part}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpresnum}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\space}
```

But it is language depended because I specify the name of the partname manually. I would rather have something which print automatically the partname according to the language.

I tried:

```
 \renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname~}
```

but it does not work. **It seems babel package create an error when I select French as language.**

MWE (not compiling because of babel):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname~}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Name of the part 1}
\label{part:part-1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{cha:chapter-1}


\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:section-1}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\label{sec:subsection-1}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\label{sec:subsection-2}

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:3}




\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname~}` works for me

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Indeed, it works in the MWE but not in my big document. I identified the package which blocks the compilation : babel. If I add `\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}`, I have an error. Any idea?

Comment: You must give `memoir` give a chance in order to detect the language for `babel`: Try `\documentclass[french]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Comment: Test done, adding `[french]` to `memoir` package does not work, I still have an error if I select French as language in babel.

Comment: It worked for me in your MWE, have you removed the `.aux` file in between?

Comment: You specified `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. The problem occurs only with french. Did you tried  `\usepackage[french]{babel}` or   `\usepackage[english,french]{babel}`

Comment: I did as I wrote and that worked for me, using the code from your MWE with `\partname` in the `\cftpartname` redefinition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66068/discussion-between-ppr-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`french` has <strike>done changing things over the years</strike> for a long time (I don't know since when) a specific deal with `\partname`. Jump to bottom of answer for the brief version. This is in fact a *long-standing* problem... (which I bump into again every few years).

---

Thus you need to communicate version numbers (check the log). Perhaps option `PartNameFull=false` will help in your case if you use <strike>latest</strike> not too old version of `french`. You can find its documentation in French at [this location](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/index.html). Check particularly pages 13 and 14 of this French language documentation.

[I know my answer is presumably not what is at stake here, I will delete this once the actual question is clarified]

#### Incomplete explanation

In fact I had encountered similar issue in the past. The toc file will contain

```
\contentsline {part}{\partnumberline {I}Name of the part 1}{3}
```

Then the expansion of `\l@part` at some point invokes (using up-to-date TL2017 as of today 2017/09/23)

```
\FB@partname  ->\ifFBPartNameFull \csname ordinal\romannumeral \value {part}\endcsname \space \frenchpartnameord \FB@emptypart \else Partie\fi
```

But at this stage when the TOC is typeset, the part counter is at zero. Hence we end up with `\ordinal` which fetches `\space` as argument. But `french.ldf` only defines `\ordinali`, `\ordinalii`,  etc... macros:

```
   \SetStringLoop{ordinal#1}{%
     \frenchpartfirst,\frenchpartsecond,Troisième,Quatrième,%
     Cinquième,Sixième,Septième,Huitième,Neuvième,Dixième,Onzième,%
     Douzième,Treizième,Quatorzième,Quinzième,Seizième,%
     Dix-septième,Dix-huitième,Dix-neuvième,Vingtième}
```

and never defines `\ordinal`. The `\ordinal` macro is provided by `memoir` class.

```
$ latexdef -c memoir ordinal
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\\\@protected\@testopt { <-- HERE ?\\.*? }? *(\\\\.*?) / at /usr/local/bin/latexdef line 391.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\\\@testopt { <-- HERE ?(\\.*?) }?/ at /usr/local/bin/latexdef line 394.

\ordinal:
macro:#1->\begingroup \let \fnumbersep \relax \form@tnumber {#1}\let \ordstring \nthstring \ifnum \c@xsm@mctr =\@ne \else \ifcase \c@ism@mctr \or \let \ordstring \iststring \or \let \ordstring \iindstring \or \let \ordstring \iiirdstring \fi \fi \ordscript {\ordstring }\endgroup
```

and it ends up in an error with `#1` being `\space`.

(please someone, tell me how to get rid of the annoying warnings from usage of `latexdef` ...)

I am sure I met this earlier, but I forget the details.

Using

```
\frenchsetup{PartNameFull=false}
```

is workaround because it avoids the bad branch in

```
\FB@partname  ->\ifFBPartNameFull \csname ordinal\romannumeral \value {part}\endcsname \space \frenchpartnameord \FB@emptypart \else Partie\fi
```

Alternative is to do `\setcounter{part}{1}` before the TOC, but this is just proof of concept because result is of course bad.

#### The gist of it, in short

The `\tableofcontents` executes `\l@part` and the latter will expand under memoir class the `\cftpartname`.

If you modify `\cftpartname` to use the babel `\partname`, then with French babel module, this will, by default try to expand to something which depends upon the *current value* of the **part** counter.

But, typically, the `\tableofcontents` is before the first `\part`, thus the `part` counter has value zero. The `french.ldf` code does not foresee that `part` could be zero, and ultimately an error is raised due to the fact that the memoir `\ordinal` macro is expanded with a wrong argument.

---

In essence, `french.ldf` by default makes usage of `\partname` in the TOC resulting into at best non-sense, and at worst a TeX error at some stage. It restricts its use to the sectioning units themselves only.

(so what goes in the `.toc` file is already expanded and ok; the problem is if the `.toc` file itself attempts to use on its own `\partname`)

Comment: You answer is very relevant. Adding `\def\frenchpartname{Partie}` or `PartNameFull=false` inside `\frenchsetup{}` fixes the problem.

Comment: well, turns out this problem is mentioned in the [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) code comments: _because `\frenchpartname` does things depending on the current
value of the counter part. ... under class memoir the bug showed up._ And the `v1.08b [2015/03/18]` "Change history" entry in the doc contains: *`\etocpartname` ... was defined to be `\partname`, but this is not compatible at least with babel+french context. Now simply expands to Part.*